# Allow Facebook page users/fans to post only after admin review?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I run a Facebook page for a local organization.  Is it possible to allow users to post on our wall, tag photos, etc. - but only after one of our admins has reviewed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the ability to screen and review comments and posts.

Here is a direct quote from Facebook

To prevent posts by everyone from appearing on your Page's timeline ****until you review them:****

- From the top of your Page, click Edit Page  and select Edit Settings
- Click Post Visibility
- Select Hide posts by others on my Page timeline from the dropdown menu
- Click Save Changes
- Visit the Activity Log each day to choose which posts should be allowed on your Page's timeline for everyone to see

source:  https://www.facebook.com/help/356113237741414

Comment: @AlEverett Fixed. Anyway, thanks, @user46710! It might be that it just recently became possible, but now it works so that makes your answer the correct one.